# Custom hook add action in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, hook

I am developing a plugin but I have a trouble because I don't get hook an action to a function and show the content. I am noob developer Wordpress Plugins so sorry if i do stupid stuff. My plugin starts in page1.php and when I press a submit button to page2.php, I have a function which I want hooking, but I've tried this add_action and didn't work and I don't know which tag is the correct, if i need add some more or what can be happenning. I read several times the documentation and I've tried somethings as I said but nothing. All help is welcome, thanks in advance.

```
//page2.php
function testFunction(){
    echo "hello";
}

add_action('page2_page', 'testFunction');
add_action('init', 'testFunction');
```

Comment: What is your `'page2_page'` pointing to? You may first, start by troubleshooting, hooking your function to an existing predefined location by WordPress. You can do so by editing your initial `hello.php` and hook your function to the `admin_notices` area of the dashboard, then, enable it (the `Hello Dolly` plugin); you should see **hello** printed in the notification area of your dashboard. BTW: did you registered your plugin as expected? What was your approach?

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress has built in actions, like `init`, which allow you to hook code in certain places.  However, `page2_page` is not a built in action.  Therefore, to use it, you would have to add the code `do_action( 'page2_page' );` wherever you want your code to be called.  Basically, that will run all of the code that has been hooked to the `page2_page` tag.

Having said that, using custom actions might be an incorrect/unnecessarily complicated way to achieve whatever you're trying to do. Clicking a button and then having more content appear without reloading the page requires a Javascript implementation.